# Is it good to use Graph DB to store products catalogue like information?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, product, catalog

I am new to Graph DB and hope I understand its purpose by now. My requirement is to store products(electrical components) catalogue information with few millions entries and their physical compatibility relationship. I need to search and pick items compatible to the one in hand and drill further based on the resultant list of components.

Is Graph DB (like Neo4J) the right choice for this? Is there a better alternate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are actually a few customers doing exactly that.

Graphs are great for trees. You can easily aggregate information across the tree and collect children or find dependencies.

Here is an example blog post on that topic:

- http://blog.bruggen.com/2015/07/hierarchies-and-google-product-taxonomy.html
- http://blog.bruggen.com/2014/03/using-neo4j-to-manage-and-calculate.html